# How to create loading component in Angular 11

Tags: angular, loading, angular11

I need to create a loading component with **Angular 11**.
When loading data, for example, I want my **loading-component** to be displayed otherwise other components should work.

I don't have a proper idea to do this?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

you can create fullscreen loading overlay in app component and to show and hide that component use service and observable

app component:
html:

```
<div *ngIf="loadingService.isLoading$ | async">Loading...</div>
```

ts:

```
constructor(public loadingService: LoadingService) {

}
```

loading service:

```
class LoadingService {
  private isLoading = new Subject<boolean>();
  isLoading$ = this.isLoading as Observable;

  toggleLoading(val: boolean) {
    this.isLoading.next(val);
  }
}
```

to start loading from any component inject service and call toggle loading method:

```
constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService) {
  this.loadingService.toggleLoading(true);
}
```

there can be some syntax errors or typos in this code as i have not tested it, just sharing the idea
let me know if you face any other problem